# Why does the error occurs then I try to utilize pzRDExportWrapper in Pega 7.1.8?

Tags: pega

I have a task to export a repeat grid's content to Excel. I have read an
[article](https://pdn.pega.com/support-articles/how-export-data-grid-excel), but I still can't realize how to properly use it. I tried to repeat article's steps to provide pzRDExportWrapper, but after I click "Save" button I get the error:

> Method: Rule-Obj-Activity instance not found:
> Sb-FW-CTrackFW-Work.pzRDExportWrapper. Details: Invalid value for
> Activity name passed to ActivityAssembler.

Could anybody give me any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoke activity from another activity which applies to class `Sb-FW-CTrackFW-Work`. *Rule Resolution* use primary context `Sb-FW-CTrackFW-Work` class and try invoke activity `pzRDExportWrapper` from it and you get error (because *rule resolution* can't found invoked activity in this class).

Activity `pzRDExportWrapper` applies to `Rule-Obj-Report-Definition` class. Try invoke from it.

Try activity step as below:

```
    Call Rule-Obj-Report-Definition.pzRDExportWrapper
```

Or use step page for this step which defined as applies to `Rule-Obj-Report-Definition` class(you can declare it on *Pages&Classes* tab)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please, could you explain me that do you mean? I can't get how to do this.

Comment: @o.byelyenov if it helped, please mark answer as resolved.

Comment: Thanks, it helped to remove the issue message, but the export to excel does not work. And also I can't get which page I need to use as step page.

Comment: I just resolved your issues. If you want to develop export to excel try to use tracer tool for debug.

Comment: What about step page. I mean that you can direct invoke activity from class `Rule-Obj-Report-Definition` OR can use step page (ex. declare  `TempPage` applies to class `Rule-Obj-Report-Definition` and then use `TempPage` as context for activity step where u `Call pzRDExportWrapper`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to try to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141428/discussion-between-njc-and-o-byelyenov).

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I have resolved the issue (thank you njc). I have two sections on a lone web page. 
A context of the first section is my custom data page Co-Name-FW-Data-Search. The Search page has some single value properties which are initialized by an user via an UI.
The second section is a repeat grid section, a report definition as a source. My Search page pointed out in a Pages and Classes tab. Also there is a Page, which is created by report definition and contains results. The report definition takes Search’s values as parameters.

So, I have created an activity and passed the Search page and a Cods-Pega-List MyResultList as parameters. There are some steps in the activity:

1. Check if Search is null. If true- skip step; else - transfer Search properties into Params props with Data Transform.
2. Set Param.exportmode = "excel"
3. Call pzRDExportWrapper with Step Page MyResultList.pyReportDefinition. Pass current parameter page.

P.S.: If it doesn’t work try to play with report definition’s settings.

P.P.S.: An only minus of pzExportWrapper is that it invokes report definition again.